# Contact List Android, showing only users who have installed the app

Tags: java, android, contact-list

I'm making an Android app, and I already have a contact list implemented, it is working fine. The problem is: my app is showing to the user all contacts they have added on their mobile. I want to show only the contacts that have installed my app.

I think it is possible! I have an example: Whatsapp, they only show users who have their app installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WhatsApp each user registers with his phone number. The app is syncing the contacts on the device with the known list from the WhatsApp-Servers. For this it is sending all contacts to the WhatsApp-Server. The server replies which contacts are known. Then for each contact you can show which contact has installed the app.